# Converting a JQuery AJAX request to cURL or native PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, curl

I have the following jquery AJAX code that works fine with my server.

```
                $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "myserverthing.php",
                data: {time: timestamp,
                       prog: progName,
                       qual: qualifier,
                       level: lvl, 
                       msg: message 
                }
            });
```

I need to convert it either to cURL or native PHP.

Assume all of the variables exist, are strings, and contain a value which may contain special characters.

There is no response offered by or expected from the server.

OK, let's play your way.

So far after some significant research along several avenues, what I came up with is this:

```
       $url = "myserverthing.php";
    $fields = array(
                    'time'=>urlencode($time),
                    'prog'=>urlencode($progName),
                    'qual'=>urlencode($qual),
                    'level'=>urlencode($type),
                    'msg'=>urlencode($message)
                    );

    //url-ify the data for the POST
    $fields_string = "";

    foreach($fields as $key=>$value) {
        $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&';
    }
    rtrim($fields_string,'&');

    //open connection
    $ch = curl_init();

    //set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    //execute post
    curl_exec($ch);
```

And what happens is "nothing", the server doesn't seem to "see" the request.

But the first line of the server code is not executed as it is when I make the AJAX request.

That first line of code writes the output of a print_r of the REQUEST to a file.  That output is written when the AJAX access is made but not for the cURL access.

Again, any thoughts?

Regards,
Jim

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but ***you need to help yourself first. :-)*** After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: SO is not a free coding service. Open up cURL manuals, try some things and come back with more exact problem.

Answer (score 1):

OK i'm here to help

```
<?php


$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://linktofile.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
            "value1=data1&value2=data2");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$server_output = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close ($ch);
//The output store in $server_output

?>
```

Comment: KidKupy, many thanks that did it once I also sorted out the URL.  I used the same format I did for ajax and it did seem to work.

Comment: ajax - ../../../lib/myserverthing.php but for cURL i seemed to need localhost/lib/myserverthing.php.  Aany thoughts on generalizing the URL between the two.